# Estimate on the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ is positive definite symmetric (real) matrix such that
$$-\delta\leq a_{ij}-\delta_{ij}\leq \delta.$$ Is it true that
the eigenvalues of $A$, denoted by $\{\lambda_i\}$, satisfy
$$1-\gamma \delta\leq\lambda_i\leq 1+\gamma \delta$$
for some $\gamma$ independent of the matix.
We may assume that $\delta$ is small enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.  Consider the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} + \delta \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
Where $\delta > 0$ is as small as you'd like.  Note that $A$ has eigenvalues $\delta, 2 + \delta$ which do not become arbitrarily close to $1$.

It is true, however, that the eigenvalues of $A$ can be made arbitrarily close those of the $n \times n$ matrix of $1$s, which are $\{n,0,\dots,0\}$.

---

The answer to your newest question is yes.  In fact, there's a nice proof.  Define $\|\cdot\|$ denote the $2$-norm, i.e.
$$
\|M\| = \max_{x \in \Bbb R^n; \|x\| = 1} \|Mx\|_2
$$
Let $I$ denote the identity matrix (the matrix with entries $\delta_{ij}$).  We note that because $A$ is symmetric,
$$
\|A - I\| = \max_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|\lambda - I|
$$
Now, let $M = A - I$. We know that $|m_{ij}| < \delta$.  It suffices, now, to find a $\gamma$ so that $\|M\| < \gamma \delta $. In particular, we have the fairly easy to show inequality
$$
\|M\| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{ij} |m_{ij}|^2} 
\leq \sqrt{\sum_{ij} \delta^2} = \sqrt{n^2\delta^2} = 
n\delta
$$
So, in particular, we can always take $\gamma = n$, the size of $A$.

Comment: I have posted my question incorrectly, I mean to ask what I have written now.

Comment: What are $\delta_{ij}$? Is that the kronecker delta?

Comment: $\delta_{ii}=1$, otherwise zero.

Comment: See my latest edit.

Comment: I think that's basically Weyl's inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality

Comment: should not it be $n\delta$, we have $n^2$ entries.

Comment: @timhortons fixed.  And we could have used Weyl's inequality, but we'd still need an upper bound for the eigenvalues of $M$ in terms of its entries.

Comment: In fact, if the matrix we were comparing to $A$ was anything other than the identity matrix, we would *need* something like Weyl's inequality to get something involving $\max |\lambda_i - \mu_i|$ (where for us, $\mu_i = 1$).